# Getting duplicate rows while fetching data in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i am trying to fetch data in laravel mysql while I am getting duplicate rows. I means I have two rows of same login user in database while  I am getting 6 results. Please help me.
My controller code is here

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use PDF;
use Auth;

class PdfController extends Controller
{
 public function publicationpdf()
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $data['data'] = DB::table('users') ->join('publications', 'users.id', '=', 'publications.user_id') ->join('education', 'users.id', '=', 'education.user_id') ->select('publications.*','education.research_area') ->where('users.id',$user_id)
            ->get();
        if(count ($data)>0){
            return view('pdf/publicationpdf',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            return view('pdf/publicationpdf');
        }
    }
}
```

My view code is here where I am trying to fetch data.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container"><br>


    <h4>Name: {{ Auth::user()->tname }}</h4>



    <div class="text-center">
        <h3>Publications Details</h3>
    </div><br/>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Publication Title
            </th>
            <th>Research Area</th>
            <th>Publication Year</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($data as $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$value->title}}</td>

            <td>{{$value->research_area}}</td>

            <td>{{$value->year}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach

    </table>


</div>

@endsection
```

Resulting data picture is given here. You can see the duplicated rows here.
[image: result of view or querry runnig]

All the three tables are given where I want to join the two tables publications and education
education table
[image: education table]

Here is publication table
[image: publication tables]

Here is users table give.

[image: users table]

Comment: There are no duplicate rows in the image.

Comment: You can see in image that Bilal Khan First Publication prints theree times while it is stored only one time in database. Two rows printed six times here.

Comment: See the values of other columns. They are different. When you say `row`, it's means all columns and not just values of a single column. I can see that you did a join on some tables and got these. So, it's clear that one primary id of first table had many rows connected to it in the second table showing a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Hes you are right, I want to print the result one time, I means that I want to print publication title and publication year from publication table, and research_area from education table while these two tables are connected through foreign key user_id with users table. So How I can fetch the result?

Comment: Hes you are right, I want to print the result one time, I means that I want to print publication title and publication year from publication table, and research_area from education table while these two tables are connected through foreign key user_id with users table. So How I can fetch the result?

Comment: You will have to show me the tables you want to join, how are they connected and the desired output you would like to have. Show it by editing your post and ping me again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183059/discussion-between-irfan-khan-and-vivek-23).

Comment: what is connect `educations.research_area` , `publications.title` what is connection between tow tables just think what you need ? i guess you need to include `publications.id` into `educations` table

Answer (score 0):

As you join with multiple table you have to use **Group By** on your query Either it's will give to you duplicate data of your join table .

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by to avoid duplicate records. It will group all your duplicate records at a single one.
Eg

```
->groupBy('THE COLUMN NAME')
```

Remember, You must use "select" before using groupBy.

```
Select('THE COLUMN NAME') then groupBY ('THE COLUMN NAME')
```